# CASE WHEN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
 SET @Result = @KriteriumTekst + 
               CASE @Operator 
                  WHEN 'LT' THEN '<'
                  WHEN 'GT' THEN '>'
                  WHEN 'NE' THEN '<>'
                  WHEN 'EQ' THEN '='
               + @Verdi + 
               CASE @Tilstand 
                  WHEN 'OG' THEN 'AND'
                  WHEN 'ELLER' THEN 'OR'
```

This statement is not compiling, what could be the issue.

Comment: All the variables are assumed to be properly declared, aren't they?

Comment: yes, they are properly declared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are miising the `END` of the `CASE` expressions:

```
 SET @Result= @KriteriumTekst+CASE @Operator WHEN 'LT' THEN '<'
                                        WHEN 'GT' THEN '>'
                                        WHEN 'NE' THEN '<>'
                                        WHEN 'EQ' THEN '='
                              END

                    +@Verdi+ CASE @Tilstand WHEN 'OG' THEN 'AND'
                                            WHEN 'ELLER' THEN 'OR'
                             END
```

Comment: @Thanks, End was missing from the query.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in comments, your cases needs to be terminated with `END`

Other than that, if `@Operator` is "LT" and `@Tilstand` is "OG", you'd have a result that looks like

```
@KriteriumTekst + '<' + @Verdi + 'OG'
```

Given values to `@KriteriumTekst` and `@Verdi`, you may end up with something like

```
@Result = '1<5OG'
```

It is difficult to see what you would want to do with that string.

Comment: You mean `'1<50AND'` of course. But it's hard to think of any reason to do this. Unless you are building queries with dynamic SQL - and you'll need spaces between the operands in that case.

Comment: @ypercube: I do mean `AND` of course! And yes, it is the lack of spaces as well as the fragmented nature of that clause that worries me. We can't really tell what the problem is going to be unless we see how `@Result` is used. Dynamic SQL may be warranted at times, but it is easy to get lost in these conditional string concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the case statement:

```
SET @Result= @KriteriumTekst+CASE @Operator WHEN 'LT' THEN '<'
                                        WHEN 'GT' THEN '>'
                                        WHEN 'NE' THEN '<>'
                                        WHEN 'EQ' THEN '='
                                        END
                    +@Verdi+ CASE @Tilstand WHEN 'OG' THEN 'AND'
                                            WHEN 'ELLER' THEN 'OR'
                                            END
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `CASE` requires the `END` keyword ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms181765.aspx)):

```
declare @result nvarchar(256)
declare @KriteriumTekst nvarchar(256)
declare @Operator nvarchar(256)
declare @Verdi nvarchar(256)
declare @Tilstand nvarchar(256)

set @KriteriumTekst = 'Tekst '
set @Operator = 'LT'
set @Verdi = 'Verdi '
set @Tilstand = 'OG'
 SET @Result= @KriteriumTekst+CASE @Operator WHEN 'LT' THEN '<'
                                        WHEN 'GT' THEN '>'
                                        WHEN 'NE' THEN '<>'
                                        WHEN 'EQ' THEN '=' END
                    +@Verdi+ CASE @Tilstand WHEN 'OG' THEN 'AND'
                                            WHEN 'ELLER' THEN 'OR' END
select @result
```